# Run type error 13 - type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting a **Run type error 13 - type mismatch** at

the following line:

```
   Set cel = wshS.Columns(1).Find(What:="EMEA\" + wshT.Cells(r, 10 + cCtr).Value, _
   LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
```

Do you know what could be causing it? What does it mean?

Full code below:

```
Sub VDA_Update()

Dim wshT As Worksheet
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wshS As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim m As Long
    Dim cel As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wshT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Check whether vda.xlsx is already open
    Set wbk = Workbooks("vda.xlsx")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If wbk Is Nothing Then
        ' If not, open it
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Working\vda.xlsx")
    End If

    ' Set worksheet on vda.xlsx
    Set wshS = wbk.Worksheets("pc_list")
    m = wshT.Cells(wshT.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop though cells in column J on main.xlsm
    For r = 1 To m

        For cCtr = 0 To 2

        ' Can we find the value in column A of vda.xlsx?
        Set cel = wshS.Columns(1).Find(What:="EMEA\" + wshT.Cells(r, 10 + cCtr).Value, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not cel Is Nothing Then

            ' If we find a match, then change cell color

            If cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "True" Then
                wshT.Cells(r, 10 + cCtr).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                wshT.Cells(r, 43).Value = "Assigned"
            ElseIf cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "False" Then
                wshT.Cells(r, 10 + cCtr).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
                wshT.Cells(r, 43).Value = "Unassigned"
            End If

            ' If so, enter "Yes" in column M - Comms Sent?
                ' If wshT.Cells(r, 13).Value = "" Then wshT.Cells(r, 13).Value = "Yes"
            ' Enter "Yes" in column O - VDA Deployed?
                If wshT.Cells(r, 15).Value = "" Then wshT.Cells(r, 15).Value = "Yes"
            ' Enter "5.6.200" in column P - VDA Version
                If wshT.Cells(r, 16).Value = "" Then wshT.Cells(r, 16).Value = "5.6.200"
            ' Enter date in column Q - Migration Date
                ' If wshT.Cells(r, 17).Value = "02/01/2014" Then wshT.Cells(r, 17).Value = "03/03/2014"

            End If
        Next
    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: check whether your cells `wshT.Cells(r, 10 + cCtr).Value` has any errors on the sheet like `#N/A`,`#VALUE!`, `#DIV/0!` and so on

Comment: Try replacing  **"EMEA\" + wshT.Cells(r, 10 + cCtr).Value** with **"EMEA\" & wshT.Cells(r, 10 + cCtr).Text**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ampersand (&) instead of a plus (+) between the segments of `What:=` that you are concatenating:

```
Set cel = wshS.Columns(1).Find(What:="EMEA\" & wshT.Cells(r, 10 + cCtr).Value, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
```

If there is one cell value in your search range `wshT.Cells(r, 10 + cCtr)` with a pure number value, VBA will try adding "EMEA\" mathematically to that number (instead of concatenating it). In this case the type mismatch would be one of text and numeric data types.